# SP2010: Count the number of times a page is opened

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model, jsom

I've a page which uses query string. I want to find how many times the page is being opened. So, I thought of running a javascript function to update a list column (Page Views) every time the page loads. I first needed to identify the item ID which needs to be updated. I was able to do this by running the below function -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {               
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(updatePageViews, "sp.js");          
});

function updatePageViews() {

    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Topics');
    var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    allItems = list.getItems(query);
    context.load(allItems);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onItem1Updated), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onItemUpdateFailed));
}

function onItem1Updated() {

    var listEnumerator = this.allItems.getEnumerator();
    var idVar = '';
    var location = window.location.href;
    if(location.indexOf("ID=") > -1){
               var topicIdUrl = location.split("ID=")[1].split("&")[0];
            }
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        if(currentItem.get_item('Topic_x0020_ID')==topicIdUrl){
            //currentItem.set_item('Page_x0020_Views', '666');
                        //currentItem.update();
                        idVar = currentItem.get_item('ID');
        }

    }
    alert(idVar);
    var testItem = this.allItems.getItemById(idVar);
    testItem.set_item('Page_x0020_Views', '123');
    testItem.update();
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onItemUpdated), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onItemUpdateFailed));

}


function onItemUpdated() {
 alert('Item has been updated!');

}

function onItemUpdateFailed(sender, args) {
 alert('Failed!!!');

}
```

I now want to update a column (Page Views) in the Topics list where ID equals idVar. I tried the above approach but it's not updating the list item. This column's value should be incremented every time the function loads.

Answer (score -1):

I've done something like that, but I used [SharePointPlus.js](https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) to get/update list items and it is working perfectly. Maybe you should try to use SharePointPlus.js.

Comment: I haven't worked with  SharePointPlus.js. I'm curious to know why my code is not working.